# Is there a command to move the whole SVG path to a new position?

Tags: javascript, svg

Is there a command to move the whole SVG path to a new position, instead of adding the offsets to each point of the path?

Comment: Read on: groups and 'use' element

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Thanks to sehe's comment. The solution is: wrap the path into

```
<g transform="translate(offset_x,offset_y)"></g>
```

Comment: ...or alternatively just put a `transform` attribute on the `<path>` itself.

Answer (score 4):

```
<path transform="translate(x, y)" d="....">
```

If your path already has transforms and you'd rather not interfere with them:

```
<g transform="translate(x, y)">
    <path transform="..." d="....">
</g>
```

Stealing from Phrogz's comment and Powerboy's answer.